# Extract by Expression in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, extract, qgis-modeler, qgis-expression

QGIS version 3.16.16-Hannover
OS Version Linux Mint 19.3

So I am trying to run a simple Extract by location algorithm in the graphical modeler

I have as Input a polygon file with a field call NUMPOINTS that comes from counting points in polygons.

I want to extract the polygon with the maximum value

I use the expression

```
"NUMPOINTS" = maximum("NUMPOINTS")
```

I tested the expression using the algorithm outside the graphical modeler and everything works fine.

Then I go to the graphical model to create the model

[image: model]

[image: alorithm parameters]

And when I run it I get this error message

```
syntax error, unexpected $end
Error encountered while running Extract by expression
Execution failed after 0.12 seconds
```

So I open the model as a python script to try see what is happening. The corresponding code line is

```
# Extract by expression
alg_params = {
    'EXPRESSION': QgsExpression('\"NUMPOINTS\" = maximum(\"NUMPOINTS\")').evaluate(),
    'INPUT': parameters['InputPoints'],
    'OUTPUT': parameters['Test1']
}
outputs['ExtractByExpression'] = processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
results['Test1'] = outputs['ExtractByExpression']['OUTPUT']
return results
```

And when I run it from there I get the following message

```
Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for EXPRESSION
Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for EXPRESSION
Execution failed after 0.09 seconds
```

As I said before, I tested the expression outside the graphical modeler and it works fine.

I just do not understand why the algorithm is not working here or how to make it work.

What am I missing?

Comment: By the way: you write you want to use extract by expression on a polygon layer, but in your screenshot, you have `Input Points`. However, this is just a detail, see solution how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression field, select the first entry: `Value` insted of `Precalculated Value`. Then the model runs fine.

If you're using the second entry: `Pre calculated Value`, you have to enclose the expression in single qutotes `'`: `' "NUMPOINTS" = maximum("NUMPOINTS") '`

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for that, it seemed very simple and it was driving me crazy. I have tested both options you described and both worked for me